# AsNoTracking unnecessary in ToDictionary?

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21704224/does-using-asnotracking-make-a-difference-when-only-returning-fields) that, when you select just some colukmns of a table, the "AsNoTracking" is unnecessary because only whole entities can be tracked.

Example:
If Table has 4 columns (Id, Col1, Col2 and Col3), it's exactly the same to do

```
context
  .AsNoTracking()
  .Select(x => new {x.Id, x.Col1})
  .ToList();
```

or

```
context
  .Select(x => new {x.Id, x.Col1})
  .ToList();
```

So: the `AsNoTracking` is superfluous.

I wonder if it happens the same when you do a "ToDictionary". If I do:

```
context
  .ToDictionary(x => x.Id);
```

are the elements being tracked?

Also, I guess if I do something like `ToDictionary(x => x.Id, new {x.Id, x.Col1});` it won't be tracked for the same reason as before... right?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

AsNoTracking is tracking if you modified the data so you can call SaveChanges later.  Selecting a subset of the table does not mean you cannot add data to the results so setting it as NoTracking is useful to reduce overhead.

Comment: I read that when you select some fields, the entity is not tracked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21704224/does-using-asnotracking-make-a-difference-when-only-returning-fields

Comment: Ok, I see my writting was confusing. Subset I meant "some columns", not "some elements". I fix it...